# Text filling whole column IEEE template

Tags: two-column

I'm using a two-column IEEE template in overleaf. On my last page in the second column I have only a little bit of text but instead of staying together it stretches throughout the whole column and looks weird.

How can I make the text not fill the whole column?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. There is more than one "IEEE template" out there. Please provide more information.